# Indexed full text search in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, indexing, full-text-search

Is it possible (via a plugin or other way) for Eclipse to build a full text index for a project, so that searching a String does not linearly search all the files in the project?

(or does it automatically build such an index to speed up future searches?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index files used by the search component of Eclipse (like a [SearchParticipant](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/SearchParticipant.java.htm)) are in your workspace:

```
.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core
```

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg17248.html),

> These files are used by the search or some other tools in Eclipse.
>   If you remove them, they will created again when you restart Eclipse or when you will activate the indexes. Then you will see a progress bar saying the number of files that need to be indexed.

[image: Eclipse index files]

Answer (score 17):

http://code.inf.unibz.it/projects/instasearch/ (old)

**Edit:** https://github.com/ajermakovics/eclipse-instasearch

It's a plugin that does indexed search using Lucene.  Exactly what you're looking for I think.

Answer (score 1):

There's an absolutely amazing and free plugin made by Pivotal (the creators of spring) that does indexed search with realtime preview for eclipse and works really good. I use it every day and could not live without it:

Quick Search for Eclipse

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/quick-search-eclipse?mpc=true&mpc_state=

After install, it can be easily opened via ctrl+shift+L

Give it a try, in my opinion is better than eclipse instasearch, and periodically maintained

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin that does that. Using the "Builder" example in Eclipse PDE in conjunction with Lucene, it should take a novice a couple of days to get something that works.

If you are interested, [nWire](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/) (for [Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-java) or [PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php)) offers a full text search for all the elements in your code (not just types, but also methods, fields, constants, etc.). It does not index all the code, though.